# Is there a node.js default credential provider chain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm writing a node.js app that uses the AWS SDK.

The java documentation describes a very convenient concept called [the default credential provider chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html). I could not find the same concept in the [Node.js API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html).

I'm hoping that node/javascript has this as an undocumented feature.  Does the javascript API provide a default credential provider chain, and if so, how do I use it?

Comment: Both your links talk about exactly the same thing, although nodejs variant simply calls it "Setting Credentials in Node.js". There might be some technical differences (like Java having DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain class) but at the end of the day this is the same thing.

Comment: @freakish is this the javascript version? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CredentialProviderChain.html  If so, where is the documentation on how to actually use it?  What is the javascript equivalent of this java code: `AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2).build();`

Comment: There is no equivalent sensu stricto. Nodejs follows different convention. Did you read [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sdk-code-samples.html)? This [S3 example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-bucket-policies.html#s3-example-bucket-policies-get-policy) looks quite straight forward. It's a different API, but ultimately you achieve the same thing. So this looks like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to solve?

Comment: @freakish I don't see that S3 example using `AWS.CredentialProviderChain`.  Are you saying that's used behind the scenes in this example?

Comment: No, I'm saying that you have XY problem. You are stubbornly look for some Java equivalent instead of trying to solve your hidden problem in other way.

Comment: `const s3 = new AWS.S3({region: 'us-west-2'});` see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-region.html

Comment: @freakish I think you're saying by saying `new AWS.S3({region: 'us-west-2'});`, it will automatically check my environment for the appropriate credentials.  I'm not finding that to be the case.  See here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57278192/why-do-i-need-to-hardcode-credentials-to-connect-to-aws-athena-using-the-javascr

Comment: @DanielKaplan Did you find anything on this ?

Comment: @NeerajJain this is a long time ago, but if I recall, it's already included in the library and it works automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CredentialProviderChain`:

```
const awsManageStore = new AWS.SSM(AWS.CredentialProviderChain.defaultProviders);
```

Answer (score -1):

const awsManageStore = new AWS.SSM(AWS.CredentialProviderChain.defaultProviders);
console.log("awsManageStore::",awsManageStore.config.credentials)

Comment: To help people understand your answer better, please provide some extra information along with the code you shared. And, you have to use formatting so people can see your answer properly.