# Why do I need to hardcode credentials to connect to AWS using the javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-athena

I've asked [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275780/is-there-a-node-js-default-credential-provider-chain) here that leads me to believe, by default, the JavaScript AWS SDK looks for credentials in a number of places in your environment without you having to do anything.  The order of places it checks is listed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html

I've got some working code that connects to AWS Athena.  I can only get it to work if I hardcode the credentials manually, which seems to contradict the documentation above.  Here is my code:

```
export const getAthena = (): AWS.Athena => {
    if (process.env["LOCAL_MODE"] === "true") {
        const awsCredentials = {
            region: "us-east-1",
            accessKeyId: awsCredentialsParser("aws_access_key_id"),
            secretAccessKey: awsCredentialsParser("aws_secret_access_key"),
            sessionKey: awsCredentialsParser("aws_session_token")
        };
        AWS.config.update(awsCredentials);
        let credential = new AWS.Credentials({
            accessKeyId: awsCredentials.accessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey: awsCredentials.secretAccessKey,
            sessionToken: awsCredentials.sessionKey
        });
        return new AWS.Athena({credentials: credential, signatureCache: false});
    } else {
        const awsCredentials1 = {
            region: "us-east-1",
            accessKeyId: undefined,
            secretAccessKey: undefined,
            sessionKey: undefined
        };
        AWS.config.update(awsCredentials1);
        return new AWS.Athena({credentials: undefined, signatureCache: false});
    }
};

export const awsCredentialsParser = (key: string): string => {
    const homeDirectory = os.homedir();
    const awsCredentials = fs.readFileSync(homeDirectory + "/.aws/credentials", {encoding: "UTF8"});
    const awsCredentialLines = awsCredentials.split("\n");
    const lineThatStartsWithKey = awsCredentialLines.filter((line) => line.startsWith(key))[0];
    return lineThatStartsWithKey.split(" = ")[1];
};
```

As you can see, I am using an environment variable called "LOCAL_MODE".  If this is set to true, it grabs credentials from my shared credential file.  Whereas, if you're not in local mode, it sets all credentials to undefined and relies on the IAM role instead. **Isn't the documentation saying I don't have to do this?**

But, if I change my code to this, any call to athena hangs until it times out:

```
export const getAthena = (): AWS.Athena => {
    return new AWS.Athena();
};
```

If I set the timeout to a really large number, it eventually will let me know that I have invalid credentials.

**According to the documentation, shouldn't the 2nd example be find credentials the same way the 1st does? Why does the 2nd example hang?  I don't want to have to write the code above.  How do I get my code to work like the examples?**

1. Am I somehow creating `AWS.Athena()` the wrong way in the 2nd example?
2. How do I troubleshoot this to figure out why it's hanging?
3. According to the documentation, shouldn't the bottom example be doing the same thing as the top?

Comment: These two snippets are not doing the same in case when you have competing sources of credentials. According to the docs credentials are being retrieved from various sources: IAM, `credentials` file, env variables etc. The docs doesn't say anything about precedence but it has to somehow (deterministically) decide which to use. So your connection hangs because it uses credentials with higher precedence which happen to be invalid, right? My guess is that this is because of region change.

Comment: @freakish as far as I can tell, I do not.  Locally, I think I only have a credentials file.  Then again, I don't know much about IAM in general.  Can there be an IAM role my local computer has if it's on the VPN?  I thought IAM roles only apply to AWS servers/services.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think IAM matters if you didn't explicitely set it up. Although I'm not IAM expert as well. Either way, I think that the issue is related to region setup. Because you can't connect. With invalid credentials you would get an error relatively fast. Have you tried calling `new AWS.Athena({region: "us-east-1"})` or updating just region before creating new `AWS.Athena` instance?

Comment: @freakish Yeah, and it times out the same way.

Comment: Weird. Do you have more than one profile in your credentials config? If so is default the first one?

Comment: @freakish good question.  I only have one called `[aws14]`.  I renamed it to `[default]` and it worked as expected.  Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after an investigation it seems that this (i.e. the failure on your second snippet) is because you don't have the `[default]` profile in your `.aws/credentials` file. Which is a special profile. I assume that the client uses empty strings (or nulls or something) when he can't find it. Which I find amusing to be honest (should throw an exception).

Anyway, to fix that either rename the profile you have to `[default]` or setup a different profile in your code. Here's the relevant docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html

I recommend using the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable. Will make your code more portable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an IAM role, you don't need to explicitly supply any credentials, null or otherwise:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const athena = new AWS.Athena();
const params = { ... };
const rc = await athena.startQueryExecution(params).promise();
```

In fact, this works with credentials supplied via local environment variables or in a credentials/config file too. There's a [chain of credentials providers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html) that the SDK will try, one by one.

Comment: I'm not using an IAM role locally (at least not intentionally).  I'm only using an IAM role when I deploy the code.  My example pretty much already shows what you've said here (you've got 2 additional lines).

Comment: You should not need any more code than I've shown. What happens if you locally run the awscli: `aws s3 ls` and `aws athena list-named-queries`? Does it timeout?

Comment: Check the comments on the OP.  The problem is my credentials file only has one profile, but it's not named `[default]`.  Do you know how I can say that I want to use the profile named `[aws14]` instead of `[default]`?

Comment: On Mac or Linux: `AWS_PROFILE=aws14 node app.js`